# Configuring different build tools for Jenkins Instance in Openshift

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, openshift, devops

We are providing Jenkins As a Service using Openshift as orchestration platform in our corporate environment. Different teams use different tools and their version to configure jobs.

For instance, we have 3 different combinations of java and maven. 5 different version of npm, 2 different version of python.

I wanted to know what is the best practice of configuring different tools?

Do I need to create and use slave image for each combination and different version of tool?

Is it a good practice to keep a simple slave image like different jdk versions (1.7, 1.8 etc) and configure JDK, NPM, Maven, Python packages as tools and use a persistent volume on slave. So that, during build these packages are setup on the fly in the PVC.

Is that an anti-pattern to use tools this way in docker slave images?

Comment: If I was you, I'd build a Docker image which only contains necessary things. If it's going to be use by Java, only java tools. For Python, only Python tools etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have accomplished this by creating a `git` repository called `jenkins` and the structure of the repository looks like

```
master/
  plugins.txt
  config-stuff

agents/
  base/
  nodejs8/
  nodejs10/
  nodejs12/
  maven/
  java8/

openshift/
  templates/
    build.yaml
    deploy.yaml (this includes the deployment and configmaps to attach the agents)
  params/
    build
    deploy
```

We are able to build each agent independently and the master independently. We place the deployment template on the OpenShift cluster so the user has to do `oc process openshift//jenkins | oc apply -f -` to install Jenkins in a namespace. However, you should also look into [helm](https://helm.sh/) for installing Jenkins as a helm chart.

Comment: Thanks Chris, if I understand correctly you propose using dedicated images for each tool rather than having multiple tools (npm+java) on one image, is that correct? But in that case we would have to mention agent for each step separately and what if we have freestyle jobs that are configured to run on a specific node and uses multiple tools?

Comment: The application should use a wrapper for maven/gradle. Then the base image really only needs java to build the application if you are dealing with a java application. But I do think you want some separation. The main thing is building a new image with a patch/bug fix. If the images are too complex, it may be difficult to keep them from breaking other components.

Answer (score 0):

In my view is better to create images separately for tools for specific apps - Java for Java tools,  Python, only Python tools. You can use [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) that you will have all tools available from single host. You will preserve volume data when containers are created. 
Compose supports variables in the compose file. You can use these variables to customize your composition for different environments, or different users.

Compose preserves all volumes used by your services. When `docker-compose up` runs, if it finds any containers from previous runs, it copies the volumes from the old container to the new container. This process ensures that any data you’ve created in volumes isn’t lost.

Compose caches the configuration used to create a container. When you restart a service that has not changed, Compose re-uses the existing containers. Re-using containers means that you can make changes to your environment very quickly.

Here is example of compose file: [compose-file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).